# how to convert long date format to short date format in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

I want to convert `'01-Dec-2015'` date to `'2015-12-01'`. 
how i can do this in mysql.

When I am executing my query:-

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE biometric_date
SET att_date = STR_TO_DATE(att_date, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

It show me error like

```
Error Code: 1411. Incorrect datetime value: '01-Dec-2015' for function str_to_date
```

Please help me

Comment: First: never-ever store date values as strings if you want to use them as dates. There is no 'format' in the database, it only matters when you want to display the data. Do read the manual (this is why they wrote it): `STR_TO_DATE` is your friend. Second: format the code you share with us. Third: read and interpret the error message, use your favourite search engine to do your research before posting a question. This question is a clear candidate for the `Why isn't this code working` close reason. For further reference: [ask]

Comment: @shyarryg It is considered a good practice to either accept an answer or compose an answer by yourself and accept it, to state that your problem is resolved for future readers. Since I've noticed that you have a low acceptance rate (0 accepts/15 questions asked) I'd advice you to also check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)!

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE biometric_date SET att_date = STR_TO_DATE('01-Dec-2015','%d-%M-%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put **current** format as second parameter in `STR_TO_DATE()` function:

```
UPDATE date_table t SET att_date = STR_TO_DATE(t.att_date,'%d-%M-%Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like:

```
mysql> select str_to_date('01-Dec-2015','%d-%M-%Y');
+---------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('01-Dec-2015','%d-%M-%Y') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2015-12-01                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `att_date`. This might not be in required format.

You can also use [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('01-Dec-2015','%d-%m-%Y') as somecolname 
FROM tablename
```